# Dropping all duplicate rows in mySQL 5.7.9?

Tags: mysql

I want to drop all rows in a table of mySQL that have a duplicate using `GROUP BY`. My table has fields name date position email and looks like

```
+----------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
| M        | 1976-10-03    |        1 | m@gmail            |
| R        | 1982-03-26    |        2 | r@gmail.com        |
| C        | 1987-09-03    |        3 | c@gmail.com        |
| M        | 1976-10-03    |        1 | m@gmail            |
+----------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
```

I want to get

```
+----------+---------------+----------+--------------------+           |
| R        | 1982-03-26    |        2 | r@gmail.com        |
| C        | 1987-09-03    |        3 | c@gmail.com        |
+----------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
```

My attempt (from the answers to similar questions)

```
DELETE FROM ts1 WHERE * IN (SELECT * FROM ts1 GROUP BY * HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Where are the errors? I understand I'm using too many * but I want to avoid naming all columns because they are too many in my actual table. Notice that I want to check for duplicates over the entire row.

Comment: Ypu should avoid grouping on *. Try grouping on mail

Comment: check this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql i think its duplicate question

Comment: No, it's not, I'm asking how to avoid naming all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `GROUP BY *` - you want to use `GROUP BY name`:

```
DELETE FROM ts1 WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM ts1 GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Note that this would assume that users have unique names.

So you may actually want to check their emails instead:

```
DELETE FROM ts1 WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM ts1 GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Comment: Is there a way to check all fields without naming all of them?

Comment: @user3285148 Typically by that definition you are not grouping anything. In that case a `SELECT * FROM table` is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY *` ... unless you have pure duplicates across the entire row.

Comment: I have duplicates over the entire row.

Comment: @user3285148 - well there are no shortcuts to list them all out AFAIK. You can't say `GROUP BY *`, you have to list out every column. I'd get to typing if you have a lot of columns and need to check every column.

Comment: If I type your command I get the following error
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'ts1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: And, could you write the command by listing explicitly all the fields, not just the email field?

Comment: For future reference: In case you get "ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'ts1' for update in FROM clause"
You can use something like this to avoid it
DELETE FROM ts1 WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM (SELECT * FROM ts1) AS x GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*)>1);